# pandas and numpy logic using 'isin' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Trying to create a query that returns either 3 or 2 or 1

Table

```
ID   Field1   Field2
1    J        JLP10A
2    J        JLP22A
3    S        JLP25C
```

I want if Field1=J AND the first 4 letters of Field2='JLP10' then return 3, else if Field1=J then return 2 else return 1.
So ID 1 should return 3, ID 2 should return 2 and ID 3 should return 1.

I have tried the following:

```
Table=Table.assign(Field3=np.where(((Table.Field1=='J')&(Table.Field2.astype(str).str[0:4].isin(['JLP10', 'JLP15']))),3, np.where(Table.Field1=='J'),2,1))))
```

This does not return 3 for ID1..

When I remove the [0:4] condition and make Field2 actually match I get 3 for ID1.

```
Table=Table.assign(Field3=np.where(((Table.Field1=='J')&(Table.Field2.isin(['JLP10A', 'JLP15']))),3, np.where(Table.Field1=='J'),2,1))))
```

So the code is not reading the 0:4 correctly.. any ideas why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of ')' is wrong  :-) , and for `str[0:4]` should be `str[0:5]`

```
Table=Table.assign(Field3=np.where((Table.Field1=='J')&(Table.Field2.astype(str).str[0:5].isin(['JLP10', 'JLP15'])),3, np.where(Table.Field1=='J',2,1)))
Table
Out[124]: 
   ID Field1  Field2  Field3
0   1      J  JLP10A       3
1   2      J  JLP22A       2
2   3      S  JLP25C       1

#Table=Table.assign(Field3=np.where((Table.Field1=='J')&(Table.Field2.astype(str).str.startswith('JLP10','ABCD')),3, np.where(Table.Field1=='J',2,1)))
```

Comment: WEN YOU THE BEST! But can you explain why it is 0:5? Wouldnt that mean first 6 characters??

Comment: @babz nope , it will be first 5 character :-) that why we also can do `str[:5]`

Comment: I am really sorry but there are cases where Field2 is 'ABCD  ', 2 blank spaces at the end. This script returns an error for those cases saying 'invalid character in identifier'

Comment: @babz before you doing those condition `Table.Field2=Table.Field2.str.strip()`, link here   https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html

Comment: **Table=Table.assign(Field3=np.where((Table.Field1=='J')&(Table.Field2.astype(str).str[0:5].isin(['JLP10', 'ABCD '])),3, np.where(Table.Field1=='J',2,1)))** in this case [0:5] would be 'ABCD ' but that seems to be an invalid character

Comment: @babz let us try `str.startswith` `Table=Table.assign(Field3=np.where((Table.Field1=='J')&(Table.Field2.astype(str).str.startswith('JLP10','ABCD')),3, np.where(Table.Field1=='J',2,1)))`

Comment: you are the greatest.. amazing solution, saved me hours of agony

Comment: @babz aha, just try my best to help :-)